# How to Update LSP in Lunarvim?

Tags: editor, updates, lunarvim

I want to update the LSP in LunarVim and I think it is not :LspUpdate.
It would be a great help if I get a command to update all LSP servers.

Tried using :LspUpdate

Answer (score 0):

To update a LSP you can use the install command.

```
:LspInstall python
```

The Lsp you are using will change depending on what language you are using and some languages have multiple installed but here is an example for jedi-language-server which is a python language server if you want to get more specific than LspInstall.

```
:MasonInstall jedi-language-server
```

To view your installed language servers you can use `:Mason` to bring up a GUI to view the installed servers.

Additionally, if you would like to install a specific version you can specify with the `@` sign for example:

```
:MasonInstall jedi-language-server@0.40.0
```

I recommend looking at `:h Mason` for more information on Mason which manages LSPs, Linters, etc. inside of LunarVim.